# ionic 3 iframes sometimes not loading in ios, works good in android and ios in ionic view

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, iframe

I am creating a video tutorials app using ionic 3. The videos are rendered in iframes from vimeo. There can be 10-12 iframes on a course page which are all loaded at once after the view is loaded.

There is a strange issue of some videos not loading sometimes when I go to the course page. Issue is only with iphones when tested on emulator and actual device using test flight. Issue does not seem to happen when tested with ionic view app in iphone.

[photo of how it looks with some videos not loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY2SR.png)

I have already added

```
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

to the config.xml so that all urls are supported by the iframes in ios.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it by changing the above code to
<allow-navigation href="*" />